# Pyomo - Set maximum number of function evaluations using baron solver

Tags: solver, pyomo

I would like to set the maximal number of function evaluations when using Pyomo (with the BARON solver). My code is:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
opt = SolverFactory('baron')
m = ConcreteModel()
m.x1 = Var(bounds=(-10.0, 10.0))
m.x2 = Var(bounds=(-10.0, 10.0))
m.o = Objective(expr=(2.0 * m.x2 + m.x1 - 7.0) ** 2.0 + (2.0 * m.x1 + m.x2 - 5.0) ** 2.0)
results = opt.solve(m) # maxEvaluations=5
print results
```

where the `expr` corresponds to Booth' function. **I would like to set the maximal number of function evaluations as the terminating criteria**. How can I achieve this?

If it is also possible to get a more verbose output of results, ideally listing the running best result with the number of function evaluations, then that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send options to solvers as a dictionary using the `options` keyword argument for the `solve` method.  Options are passed through to the solver verbatim.  You will need to look at the individual solver documentation to see what options it supports (for BARON, see [here](http://www.minlp.com/downloads/docs/baron%20manual.pdf)). For example:

```py
solver = SolverFactory('baron')
solver.solve(model, options={'MaxIter': 5})
```

If you want to watch the solver process in realtime, you can tell Pyomo to not suppress the solver stdout/stderr output using the `tee` option:

```py
solver.solve(model, options={'MaxIter': 5}, tee=True)
```

As almost all solvers are launched as separate subprocesses, there is (currently) no way for Pyomo to get intrusive information (like the current incumbent variable values) during the solver execution.